# Antonym for "luxurious laziness"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is an antonym of "luxurious laziness"? Here is the context:

> Going to school by a 20-minute bicycle journey is [[*antonym*]], while going to school by a 15-minute motorcycle ride is *luxurious laziness*.

Why is it a luxurious laziness? Luxurious because a motorcycle is costly. Laziness because the time difference is almost insignificant, and by riding a bicycle you're also building up your health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Andrew's answer, but let's say that you wanted to keep your original sentence structure for dramatic effect. Let's also change **luxurious laziness** to something that rolls off the tongue more easily. How about:

> Going to school by a 20-minute bicycle journey is **yeomanly industry**, while going to school by a 15-minute motorcycle ride is **indolent decadence**.

Or let's break the sentence apart for comic effect, to communicate disbelief with a mocking or sarcastic tone:

> Going to school by a 20-minute bicycle journey is  **yeomanly industry**, but going to school by a 15-minute motorcycle ride? Why, that is **indolent decadence**.

OK, let's just drop all pretense and go all out with this thing!

> "Going to school by a 20-minute bicycle journey is **yeomanly industry**," the overweening governor told the incredulous young man, "but going to school by a 15-minute motorcycle ride? Why, that, my boy, is **indolent decadence**. Back in my day we had to walk *15 miles* in the snow *each way* and our shoes were made of bark!"
>
> And with that scolding, the governor sauntered off to his limousine which awaited him. The Duchess of Yarmouth would not be kept waiting!

Comment: Wow! :D That's a great answer! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree with you that riding a motorcycle counts as either *luxury* or *laziness* ... but, putting that aside.  Both *slothful* and *indolent* mean "excessive laziness*.

> He was an **indolent** child, used to laying in bed until well after noon, followed by a leisurely breakfast.

Antonyms are: *energetic, industrious, diligent, studious, hard-working*, etc.

> His brother, however, was a **diligent** child, always rising before the dawn to study.

I'm not sure this quite fits your context, though.  It sounds more like you want to say that, by riding a motorcycle, you're *giving in* to a desire not to work hard.  In this case, "self-indulgent" fits:

> Riding a bicycle to school every day is **good exercise**, while taking a motorcycle to go the same distance is **simple self-indulgence.**

Comment: Yes, "self-indulgent" correctly fits my intended meaning. This version is much better! Thanks (+1)